# Why does this setjmp program print a 5?

Tags: c++, setjmp

The following code just ends up printing "5"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <setjmp.h>

static jmp_buf buf;

float funcB()
{
    setjmp(buf);
    return 1.6f;
}

int funcA()
{
    longjmp(buf,5);
    std::cout<<"b";
    return 2;
}

int main()
{
    funcB();
    std::cout<<funcA();
}
```

But this doesn't make any sense, as setjmp is returning 5, not either function...
Don't worry, I'm not using this code anywhere, I'm just curious!

Comment: Note: using setjmp/longjmp in C++ is just wrong. We have throw and catch here.

Comment: Agreed, I was just curious about how much they'd screw things up

Comment: @foips They (nearly always) cause undefined behaviour, which is about as screwed-up as you can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to do is specifically designated as undefined behavior in the [documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/longjmp.html):

> The `longjmp()` function restores the environment saved by the most recent invocation of `setjmp()` in the same thread, with the corresponding `jmp_buf` argument. If there is no such invocation, or **if the function containing the invocation of `setjmp()` has terminated execution in the interim**, the behaviour is undefined.

Since the function that called `setjmp` (i.e. `funcB`) has exited before you call `longjmp` in `funcA`, the behavior is undefined ([it crashes on ideone](http://ideone.com/k3lKlb)).

Comment: Ah ok I get it. But still, the 5 comes from the longjmp value param, and changes with that value. It'd be interesting to see why that happens in terms of the program assembly

Comment: Also to note, I'm compiling it in clang

Comment: @foips One way why this could happen is if the compiler returns values through a designated register. Since `funcB` returns a `float`, loading `1.6f` into the register for return does not change the value in the register that is used for returning integer results. That is why `5` remains in the return register at the time when `funcA` (incorrectly) returns after a confused `longjmp`. Changing optimization level or making `funcB` return an integer may change the observed undefined behavior.

Comment: Ah sweet that would explain it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use longjmp to return to a function you have exited. In other words longjmp won't restore the stack for you. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/longjmp).

What you need is a language like scheme, where doing this kind of thing would be perfectly normal.

Comment: the code compiles and runs, what's your point? (ah, with your edit I see what you're saying)

Comment: @foips That you are using setjmp/longjmp in an illegal way and therefore your program has *undefined behaviour*. Just as if you had dereferenced a NULL pointer or something.

Answer (score 0):

It appears whatever compiler you are using is using a strict interpretation of what `setjmp` and `longjmp` do:

> This macro may return more than once: A first time, on its direct
>   invocation; In this case it always returns zero. When longjmp is
>   called with the information set to env, the macro returns again; this
>   time it returns the value passed to longjmp as second argument if this
>   is different from zero, or 1 if it is zero.

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csetjmp/setjmp/)

As it is UB, it can do this, order a pizza, end the world ... anything would be valid.